# Перемещение по сетке

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как можно реализовать перемешенные по сетке? Что бы квадрат перемещался строго по сетке и не смог остановиться посередине клеточки

[Код](https://codepen.io/Mbreti/pen/YzqMoEP)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const gridSettings = {
        squareWidth: 30,
        squareHeight: 30,
    }


    function renderGrid() {
        ctx.beginPath()
        const w = canvas.width
        const h = canvas.height
        const squareWidth = w / gridSettings.squareWidth
        const squareHeight = h / gridSettings.squareHeight
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#bdbdbd'
        ctx.lineWidth = 0.4
        for (let x = squareWidth; x < w; x += squareWidth) ctx.strokeRect(x, 0, 0.1, h)
        for (let y = squareHeight; y < h; y += squareHeight) ctx.strokeRect(0, y, w, 0.1)
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.closePath()
    }

    const drawRect = (offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0) => {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 600)
        ctx.fillRect(offsetX, offsetY, 34, 40)
        renderGrid()
    }

    drawRect(0, 0)

    const rectPos = { x: 0, y: 0 }
    const edge = (c, min, max) => Math.max(min, Math.min(max, c));

    canvas.onmousedown = (e) => {

        const start = { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY };

        canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {
            drawRect(
                edge(rectPos.x + e.offsetX - start.x, 0, 600 - 25),
                edge(rectPos.y + e.offsetY - start.y, 0, 500 - 25)
            );
        }

        canvas.onmouseup = (e) => {
            rectPos.x = edge(rectPos.x + e.offsetX - start.x, 0, 600 - 25);
            rectPos.y = edge(rectPos.y + e.offsetY - start.y, 0, 500 - 25);
            canvas.onmousemove = null
        }
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black;" width=500 height=600></canvas>
```

Comment: `let diff = e.offsetX - start.x; let x = rectPos.x + Math.floor(diff / width) * width;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо выровнять координаты по ближайшим координатам сетки (добавил в onmouseup и вынес некоторые переменные в общий доступ):

https://codepen.io/vladimir_nt/pen/pobjYKx

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const gridSettings = {
        squaresHorizontal: 30,
        squaresVertical: 30,
    }
    const w = canvas.width
    const h = canvas.height
    const squareWidth = w / gridSettings.squaresHorizontal
    const squareHeight = h / gridSettings.squaresVertical

    function renderGrid() {
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#bdbdbd'
        ctx.lineWidth = 0.4
        for (let x = squareWidth; x < w; x += squareWidth) ctx.strokeRect(x, 0, 0.1, h)
        for (let y = squareHeight; y < h; y += squareHeight) ctx.strokeRect(0, y, w, 0.1)
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.closePath()
    }

    const drawRect = (offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0) => {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 600)
        ctx.fillRect(offsetX, offsetY, 34, 40)
        renderGrid()
    }

    drawRect(0, 0)
    const rectPos = { x: 0, y: 0 }
    const edge = (c, min, max) => Math.max(min, Math.min(max, c));
    canvas.onmousedown = (e) => {
        const start = { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY };
        canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {
            drawRect(
                edge(rectPos.x + e.offsetX - start.x, 0, 500 - 34),
                edge(rectPos.y + e.offsetY - start.y, 0, 600 - 40)
            );
        }
        canvas.onmouseup = (e) => {
            var new_x = squareWidth * Math.round((rectPos.x + e.offsetX - start.x) / squareWidth);
            var new_y = squareHeight * Math.round((rectPos.y + e.offsetY - start.y) / squareHeight);
            rectPos.x = edge(new_x, 0, 500 - 34);
            rectPos.y = edge(new_y, 0, 600 - 40);
            drawRect(
                edge(rectPos.x, 0, 500 - 34),
                edge(rectPos.y, 0, 600 - 40)
            );
            canvas.onmousemove = null
        }
    }

<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Плохо смешивать отрисовку сущностей

Comment: В этом коде очень много всего, что необходимо почистить, оставляю это автору вопроса (я немного дополнил его код до рабочего, не претендуя на идеальное решение). 
Отрисовка здесь необходима, её желательно выполнять общей функцией, конечно.

Comment: @doox911 плохо усложнять обучающие примеры

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, согласен. Но, думаю, что упомянуть это стоило. Я ж не поскупился плюсом)